# INSERT, ADD, DELETE actions in GridView control with AccessDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, insert-update

I am new to programming. I am developing a web application using C#, where I have to INSERT, DELETE & UPDATE the items in GridView control of .NET which is connected to `AccessDataSource`.

I am stuck with the code. Can anyone help me by letting me know the proper background code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[have a look](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175770)

this may help

Comment: Hello @Smack, the link which you have attached is for the normal actions in ASP. I am seeking for a help to perform insert, update actions of the GRID VIEW items in ASP.net